# Outputing attribute of a variable returns the object Class instead, possible association issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model, associations

I have a cookbook app that allows users to save their favorite recipes and on their profile page (line_items index) they can get a randomized weekly menu based on their favorite recipes.  I am trying to be able to print out the ingredients of the weekly menu, but so far I can’t get it to print the name of the ingredient.  Currently when I try something like:

```
<%= line_item.recipe.ingredient.name %>
```

The result is “Ingredient”.

I suspect that it might have something to do with associations, but I can’t figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Line Items:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

Recipe:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items 
  before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
  has_many :ingredients
  has_many :directions
  has_many :users, :through => :line_items


accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, 
                              reject_if: :all_blank, 
                              allow_destroy: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :directions, 
                              reject_if: :all_blank, 
                              allow_destroy: true
validates :title, :description, :image, presence:true
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "400x400#" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  private
    #ensure that there are no line items referencing this recipe
    def ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
      if line_items.empty?
        return true
      else
        errors.add(:base, 'Line items present')
        return false
      end
    end
end
```

Ingredient:

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

Line Items View:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="menu">
 This Week's Menu
</button>
<div class="collapse in" id="menu">
  <div class="well"> 

    <br>

    <% LineItem.where(id: ids_of_line_items_this_week).each do |line_item| %>
    <li><%= line_item.recipe.title %> <%= link_to 'Replace', line_item_replace_weekly_line_item_path(line_item_id: line_item.id), method: :put, :class => "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>

    <br>
    <%= line_item.recipe.ingredients.name %> </li>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does a recipe have a single ingredient? Doesn't look like it; you'd need to iterate over the recipes `ingredients`.

Comment: Sorry.  I forgot to add the View file. I actually am iterating over the recipe. I hope this helps.

Comment: If you're iterating over the recipe ingredients then you need to have something like `<% line_item.recipe.ingredients.each %>`

Comment: Changing  <%= line_item.recipe.ingredients.name %> to <% line_item.recipe.ingredients.each %>  results in something similar to:          #<Enumerator:0x007f5af2348ec0>

Comment: ... You need to iterate over the ingredients. The block parameter will be the ingredient. Then you can do whatever you want with said ingredient. You wouldn't really want to print out the enumerator's native `to_s`.

Comment: I don't know if the github repo would help:  https://github.com/GBressler/Recipe-Box